# Lost my Google chrome bookmarks when I accidentally deleted Defalt Profile

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I find in directory C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data but not see Default, please someone help me.

Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that there is no way to restore my bookmarks without using third party software (fees may apply) and the best way to avoid the same is to sign in google account in chrome and enable sync.

Thanks for watching!